# Writing quality specifications with SpecFlow (or equivalent tool)

Tags: rspec, specifications, specflow

I've been playing with SpecFlow for the last couple of days.  During that time I realized I should brush up on writing quality specs for these systems.

Could someone point me towards some resources with best practices on creating quality specifications for SpecFlow or similar tools?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some good ressources are:

**The Cucumber Wiki**

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/

The Cucmber Wiki contains a lot of information on how to write Gherkin specifications (resp. examples like some BDD-jargons would call them)

**The RSpec Book**

http://www.pragprog.com/titles/achbd/the-rspec-book

This book has some very concrete tips on how to use Cucumber, a lot is applicable for other Gherkin- or BDD-tools in general.

**Book: Bridging the Communication Gap**

[On Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0955683610), [Book Page](http://www.acceptancetesting.info/)

A great book by Gojko Adzic about the concepts and the process of **Specification by Example**

**Upcoming Book: Specification by Example**

The new book of Gojko Adzic containing detailed information and experiences about applying "Specification by Example" in the real world.

Hopefully to be published soon (I am currently reading a review edition).

**Google Groups:**

The following groups contain plenty of information about BDD and Specification by Example:

http://groups.google.com/group/cukes

http://groups.google.com/group/behaviordrivendevelopment

http://groups.google.com/group/specflow

Comment: Cucumber wiki updated link: [https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/)